# Prevent users to access my database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a database on ssms .Now I want nobody even sysadmin have no permission on My Application Database. Is there any way that prevent users can't access to my application Database ???

Comment: **(1)** do **not** create a user for that login in your database - then that login doesn't have permissions in your database. **(2)** remove all permissions from the `public` role in your database. [Read the OVerview of SQL Server Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669078%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get an understanding of how to deal with security and permissions in SQL Server

Comment: This question is off-topic. Server configuration how-tos are not what StackOverflow is for. Besides, your question misses any indication that you have taken the time to read into SQL Server security at all. Do that first, ask *specific and detailled* questions about problems you have encountered on serverfault.com later.